# Image Modal not working when i select dropdown value to change the data

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

In my application, One of my page contains dropdown that page I have image modal when I run application open that page at first time without select dropdown value when i click image modal it works fine and it shows pop up. After when i select dropdown value at that time i click again image modal it was not working.

Thank you

Comment: Show us the dropdown and it's code. It's doing something with your modal when you selecting and option?

Comment: Hi @pwnz22, I added dropdown code. can you please see once Thank you

Comment: Try to change `img.onclick` to `img.addEventListener('click', function(){ modal.style.display = "block";   modalImg1.src = "img.PNG";    });`

Comment: Modal is opening one time or what?

Comment: yes, when i run the page at first time without changing dropdown value image modal works fine. After changing the dropdown value image modal not working.

Comment: What's going on after you change the dropdown value?

Comment: Hi i updated my code `my drop down have onselectedindexchanged="ddllist_SelectedIndexChanged" and AutoPostBack="True"` evevnts are there after changing the drop down grid will change based dropdown value

Comment: Is the `onselectedindexchanged` event somehow affects the modal `div's`?

Comment: Is the DropDownList inside an UpdatePanel perhaps?

Comment: Hi @VDWWD. Yes it is in update panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an UpdatePanel, you need to rebind javascript after a PostBack.

Wrap your javascript in a method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        bindModal();
    });

    function bindModal() {
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

        //rest of your javascript code
    }
</script>
```

Then call that method from code behind when the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event is fired.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "bindModal", "bindModal();", true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's working fine